# bullMQ waitUntilFinished function not working

Tags: node.js, redis, bullmq

I'm creating a job using BullMQ and using `waitUntilFinished` function - it's working perfect on my local machine, but it's not working on my dev server and throw an error

```
job wait credits_transaction_queue timed out before finishing, no finish notification arrived after 10000ms (id=14)
```

but it actually executed even faster than 10000ms
The job is actually executed but it didb't returns with `waitUntilFinished`
also I've tried to connect to the dev redis server to reproduce error and it seems there is some problem with redis but I don't know what exactly I need to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:
for some reason, it didn't catch `QueueEvents`, and I had to use worker events
and handle it with my own function